# data.table aggregation having trouble with NAs

Tags: r, data.table, na

I'm using the `data.table` package to aggregate a panel with multiple observations in each time-period for a given location into a panel in which there is a unique observation for a time-period-location. However, I'm having trouble aggregating for observations with an NA. While this works well:

```
set.seed(123)
data.frame(name = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), t = rep(c(1,2),3), x1 = sample(0:10,6), x2 =  sample(0:10,6))
f1

  name t x1 x2
    a 1  3  5
    a 2  7  8
    a 1 10  4
    b 2  9  3
    b 1  6  6
    b 2  0  2

f2 <- setDT(f1)[, lapply(.SD, sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(name,t), .SDcols = c("x1", "x2")]
f2

   name t x1 x2
    a 1 13  9
    a 2  7  8
    b 2  9  5
    b 1  6  6
```

Adding an NA prevents `sum()` from working:

```
f1[1,3] <- NA
f1
   name t x1 x2
    a 1 NA  5
    a 2  7  8
    a 1 10  4
    b 2  9  3
    b 1  6  6
    b 2  0  2

f2 <- setDT(f1)[, lapply(.SD, sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(name,t), .SDcols = c("x1", "x2")]
f2
name t x1 x2
    a 1 NA  9
    a 2  7  8
    b 2  9  5
    b 1  6  6
```

Whereas the x1 value for a, 1 should be 10. Any idea why this is happening even with the na.rm argument inside? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue of placing the brackets in the right spot. You should use `lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE)` instead of `lapply(.SD, sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))`. When using `lapply`, you have to add the extra parameters of the `sum`-function after the call for `sum` and not inside the call for `sum`. Furtherore, you don't need the `(x)`-part in `sum(x)`. Because the structure of `lapply` is `lapply(X, FUN, ...)`, the function specified in the `FUN`-part is automatically applied to the variable in the `X`-part.

So, your code should be:

```
setDT(f1)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(name,t)]
```

which gives:

```
   name t x1 x2
1:    a 1  0 11
2:    a 2  5  9
3:    b 2 18 12
4:    b 1  1  4
```

*Note: I left the `.SDcols = c("x1", "x2")` part out of the code as it is not needed in this case. Including it will give you the same result.*